# Laravel 8 - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7

I'm trying to access a Controller method from inside my view, but I'm getting this error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: D:\Programming\Php\Laravel\Laravel-Phone_Book\resources\views\contact_list.blade.php)
```

Here's my part of my view that's throwing the error:

```
        <tbody id="tableBody">

            @foreach ($data as $item)
            <tr>
                <!-- Test -->
                <td>{{ $item->nome }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->numero_count }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        {{ $phones = app\Http\Controllers\ContactListController::get_telefones_by_usuario($item->u_id) }}
                        @foreach ($phones as $phone)
                        <li>{{ $phone }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
```

Here's my controller function:

```
    public function get_telefones_by_usuario($id)
    {

        $telefones = Telefone::join("usuarios", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select("telefones.numero as numero")
            ->where("usuarios.id", "=", $id);
        return $telefones;
    }
```

Here's my Controller's function that injects data into my index view (that includes the view I'm trying to access the data from):

```
    public function index()
    {
        // $usuarios = Usuario::all();
        // $telefones = Telefone::all();
        $data = Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u_id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->orderBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->get();

        return view("index", compact("data"));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? `u_id` is supposed to be an integer, not an array or anything. Why is `htmlspecialchars()` not parsing it?

Thank you.

---

Edit:

Tried placing the following at the top of my partial view:

```
@inject('ContactListController', app\Http\Controllers\ContactListController")
```

Then replacing the part where I call my Controller method above with the following:

```
<?php $phones = $ContactListController::get_telefones_by_usuario($item->u_id) ?>
```

Now the error went away but I'm not getting anything back from my query, which I should:

[image]

On the Phones column there should be a list of phones associated with each person.

What's going on?

Comment: Where do you even call htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: I'm not explicitly calling it anywhere though.

Comment: `{{ ... }}` is a shortcut for `htmlspecialchars(...)` so make sure everything is strings in there (I'm looking at e.g. `{{$phone}}`

Comment: I've tried to change the blade syntax to the php tag and now I'm getting 0 results instead of that error. Please check my edit.

Comment: You are not supposed to call controller methods in a view. The controller is supposed to pass data to the view

Comment: How should I pass data to a partial view then? What would the right way to do it be?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should edit the below line.

```
$telefones = Telefone::join("usuarios", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select("telefones.numero as numero")
            ->where("usuarios.id", "=", $id)->get();
```

also when printing try to print the value using the right index.

```
<li>{{ $phone->numero }}</li>
```